# Django isn't finding my files in media/

Tags: python, django, forms, email, attachment

I am trying to create a webpage where users can fill out a form and email me their name, email address, a message, and an image.

My issue is getting the image attached to the email. When the code runs, the image is uploaded to my media root along with my other media files, but it throws an FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/2016/10/14/image.png'

Here's my models.py:

```
class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    uImage = models.FileField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d')
```

forms.py:

```
class QuoteForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    uImage = forms.FileField(required=False, help_text='5mb max.')
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py:

```
def quote(request):
    form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        subject = "Quote"
        message = "From: " + name + "\n" + "Return Email: " + from_email + "\n" + "Subject: " + subject  + "\n" + "Message: " + message

        newImage = UploadedImage(uImage = request.FILES['uImage'])
        newImage.save()
        msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email, ['zbloss@emich.edu'], reply_to=[from_email])
        image_url = newImage.uImage.url
        msg.attach_file(image_url)

        try:
            msg.send()
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thankyou')
    return render(request, "quote.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: And what is responsible for serving the files from /media?

Comment: I don't need to serve them from anywhere in particular, I thought it would be easier to have the file uploaded and then emailed to me. From there I could write a cronjob to remove the files. If there is a way to do this without uploading the image to my server that would be best case scenario!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a (non-existent) URL to `msg.attach_file`. You need to pass the location of the file on disk:

```
msg.attach_file(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, newImage.uImage.name))
```